# Shell - Looping through sql result

Tags: sql, bash

I'm deseperatly trying to loop through sql query results…
It's working quite well except that vars with spaces in strings make me weird output… like if they were considered as arrays or something like that… any idea ??

```
echo "SELECT shop_id, shop_address1, shop_address2, shop_zip, shop_city FROM base.table" | mysql -h hostname -u user -ppassword | while read -r shop_id shop_address1 shop_address2 shop_zip shop_city;
do
        echo $shop_address1
done
```

Comment: Can you give us an example? The output of the `mysql` command would be helpful.

Comment: My addresses are stored like "1 market street" and displayed like 1 1 10 11 (…) market duboce folsom (…) street street street (…).
but echo $shop_id is ok, i have 600 lines from 1 to 600 displayed… as the addresses are strangely not displayed ordered and splitted by spaces and

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of tasks I use AWK.

For example, if you want to get the first and the third columns:

```
mysql -u <USER> -p<PASSWORD> -h <HOST> < <QUERY_FILE> | awk -F"\t" '{print $1","$3;}' -
```

$X is the way to acces to the Xth column, it is like "array notation".

Obviously you can do more complex taks using AWK ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use OUTFILE to extract to csv

```
SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM test_table;
```

Then use `cut` and delimiter to access fields